# Could not find common.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.1.0)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've created a new project, but when it finish the first compile the new project return an error:

```
Error:Could not find common.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.1.0).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/core/common/1.1.0/common-1.1.0.jar
```

I've really no idea how to resolve it, hope you can help me!

Screenshots on how i'm creating a new project:

[image: Creating an android project 1]

[image: Creating an android project 2]

[image: Creating an android project 3]

[image: Creating an android project 4]

**Build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**setting.gradle**

```
include ':app'
```

I've added the gradle files because i'm thinking there is a problem there.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Add `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` before `jcenter()` in

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

it will work

---

**Update :**

*Note* : `google()` and `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` are pointing to the same repo, `google()` is a Google's Maven repo shortcut. You can add `google()` instead of `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` **IF you are using** :

> Gradle >= v.4.x+
>
> Android Studio >= 3.x+
>
> Gradle plugin for Android >= 3.x+

Comment: It seems the order is important

Comment: Can anyone explain why the order is important?

Comment: @hiddeneyes02 it seems to be a bug : instead of looking in the next repo, gradle will directly generate an error if it does not find what it looks for in the current one, so mooving google's repo to the top is the working workaround for the moment

Answer (score 10):

In both sections, you need to [add Google repo](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#google-maven)

```
 repositories {
    google() 
    jcenter()
}
```

If you upgraded Android Studio this would be done for you

Comment: Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.

Comment: The company i work for they all use android 2.2 so i need to use it too, it's sad i know :/

Comment: You need to either click the link to view the alternate URL or upgrade to use Gradle 4.1 (and configure Android Studio to use it), also mentioned in the link

Comment: Note that the order is important sometimes, my build was failing  in CircleCI because `jcenter()` was in the previous line than `google()`, so it was searching architecture components in jcenter, then failing

Comment: @voghDev Thank you for this! I was floored why my CI was complaining, this solved it for me.

Comment: @vogh There's an open Android bug tracker I found a few week ago for resolving that

Comment: Indeed @cricket_007, more colleagues here had the same problem. For the moment we have the workaround of adding  `google()` before `jcenter()` :-)