# After updating Gradle dependencies failed to resolve Firebase modules

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have updated my project to latest dependencies, also changed `compile` to `implementations` and `gradle` plugins and i have this error

> Failed to resolve: firebase-analytics Open File
>
> Failed to resolve: play-services-tasks Open File
>
> Failed to resolve: play-services-ads-identifier Open File
>
> Failed to resolve: play-services-stats Open File
>
> Failed to resolve: play-services-basement Open File

Module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



android {

    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.id"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 36
        versionName "2.04"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        //multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation files('libs/chartboost.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.github.polok:clicknumberpicker:0.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.kila.apprater_dialog.lars:apprater-dialog:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}

apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.5.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Tried a lot of combinations, can someone help?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570134/could-not-find-common-jar-android-arch-corecommon1-1-0/50570206#50570206

Comment: OMG it is work! why the order is important!?

Comment: Yes, it's a bug, the order is a workaround

Comment: Terrible! Thank you!

Comment: The order it's important because when the google dependencies are retrieved from jcenter() they are not found and instead of searching in the next repo (google()) gradle returns the error not found